# Calling a specific a general controller before the right ones?

Tags: spring-boot

I am setting up a simple website for a school project. This includes a login page. When users try to access pages that require them to be connected and they are not, I simply redirect them to the login page.

But this forces me check if the user is connected every time, which is very repetitive :

```
if (!userSession.isConnected())
        return "redirect:/connect";
```

I was wondering if it is possible to call a general controller before the others. Basically, it will check if the user is connected. If so, it redirects to the proper controller. If not, it redirect to the login page.

Scenario example :

- user U tries to connect to /home
- general controller is called
- U is not connected
- redirects to the login controller which calls the login page

Other example:

- user U tries to connect to /home
- general controller is called
- U is connected
- redirects to the proper controller according to the URL

Many thanks!

Comment: Spring Security has this all build-in. You should read up on Spring Security. You can start here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-web-filters.html

Comment: Thanks for the info